# Groovy: Add values from json to a map

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, maps

I have the following json. How can I create a dynamic map with `name` as `key` and `id` as `value`. And removing anything in `key` which has pattern (~/ ([0-9])$/) which is for example`(2)` or `(3)`

MyCode:

```
transitionsobj = jiraGetIssueTransitions(idOrKey: Jira_id)
echo prettyPrint(toJson(transitionsobj.data)) \\This prints the below json

 def fruitsMap = [:].withDefault{[]}

 transitionsobj.each {
   fruitsMap.put(transitionsobj.data.fruits.name, transitionsobj.data.fruits.id)
  }

 println "fruitsMap: ${fruitsMap}"
 println(fruitsMap.keySet());
 println(fruitsMap.values());
 println "Id of Banana is: ${fruitsMap['Banana']}"
```

JSON File:

```
   { 
"expand":"fruits",
"fruits":[ 
    { 
        "id":"131",
        "name":"Apple (2)",
        "to":{ 
            "description":"",
            "name":"Apple",
            "id":"13895"
        }
    },
    { 
        "id":"151",
        "name":"Mango",
        "to":{ 
            "description":"",
            "name":"Mango",
            "id":"13896"
        }
    },
    { 
        "id":"161",
        "name":"Banana",
        "to":{ 
            "description":"",
            "name":"Banana",
            "id":"10700"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Current Output

```
fruitsMap: [[Apple (2), Mango, Banana]:[131, 151, 161]]

[Apple (2), Mango, Banana]

[131, 151, 161]

Id of Banana is: []
```

Desired Output:

```
   fruitsMap: [
    Apple : 131 
    Mango : 151
    Banana : 161
   ]

   [Apple, Mango, Banana]

   [131, 151, 161]

   Id of Banana is: 161
```

Comment: Your json format is wrong, Jill448

Comment: updated the correct json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of

```
def fruitsMap = [:].withDefault{[]}

transitionsobj.each {
    fruitsMap.put(transitionsobj.data.fruits.name, transitionsobj.data.fruits.id)
}
```

You just need:

```
def fruitsMap = transitionsobj.data.fruits.collectEntries { 
    [it.name.replaceAll(/(?:\s+).*/, ''), it.id]
}
```